# Programmatically creating AVPlayer results in constant CUICatalog warnings

Tags: swift, uikit, avplayer, avkit, iglistkit

I'm showing video in a collection view cell of an IGListKit powered list.
This is the cell:

```
import AVKit

class ContentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  static var vc: UIViewController?

  func setup() {
    if media.fileType.starts(with: "video/") {
      return setupVideo()
    }
  }

  var videoVC: AVPlayerViewController?
  func setupVideo() {
    guard let vc = ContentCell.vc else {
      return
    }
    guard let videoVC = videoVC else {
      let videoVC = AVPlayerViewController()
      self.videoVC = videoVC
      vc.addChild(videoVC)
      self.addSubview(videoVC.view)
      setupVideo()
      return
    }

    videoVC.view.frame = bounds
    videoVC.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: media.originalSource!)!)
  }
}
```

And as soon as I start playing the video (it does play!) and scrolling the list a little, I constantly get this error:

```
2020-06-04 14:44:01.171138-0400 App[90104:5433754] [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
```

Setting a breakpoint on runtime issues doesn't shed much light:
[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Other issues with this warning pointed at image views with missing images, but I don't have an image view. The URL is also not nil, otherwise, I would get an exception instead of the warning.

Comment: I also tried this with multiple videos, the same error every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I didn't test this. But the error does indeed only happen on the Simulator. On-device it's fine. Solved.

---

Update:
Ran into the same issue again. Maybe I never actually solved it in the first place? It's been too long to know for certain. But to solve the error

```
Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
```

You can find the answer [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/4668):

> This is caused by setting the selected image field on a tab bar item in the storyboard.  Clearing this field clears the error.